# MediaElement in WPF 4.0 vs user credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, uac, credentials, mediaelement

I have a WPF application with a simple "Getting Started" .mp4 when first launching the app.

I simply added a `MediaElement` in a WPF Window and set the source to an absolute path under `C:\Program Files`.

If I launch my .exe "As Administrator", everything runs fine.
If I launch it as standard user (or by double-clicking the .exe with UAC active), the video is not shown.

The `MediaOpened` event is received, with the Source set accordingly.
The `MediaFailed` event is not fired at all.

I tried changing the way the path is packed (Uri?), I tried moving the file on another drive, tried to change the permission of the parent folder (just in case)...nothing works. The mediaElement content remains gray. If I set ScrubbingEnabled it turns black but nothing more...

I've read we cannot use resources as videoSource...so be it, I'm setting a path.

Comment: How did you set the source after moving the mp4 to another drive? Show the code.

Comment: I do not move the file runtime, I meant that I manually moved the file THEN modified my code; the path is set in my ViewModel then binded in the xaml.